# How to Include a external css file outside the application (war) in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to render css files placed external(outside war) to the application(in my local file path) to be rendered in the response....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I guess you are using jruby and assuming you are running Rails 3.1 you should read about the asset pipeline.  You can learn about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

You can also setup Rails to use an outsidea asset server by using this:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = "assets.myserver.com"
```

in the appropriate environment file

For simply loading css files outside your rails directories you can point stylesheet_link_tag to an absolute url like this:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "http://www.example.com/style.css"
```

Comment: Thanks. How could i add an css file from my local path?